# Azure AD にサインインしているユーザ情報をjavaで取得する方法

Tags: java, azure

サインインしているユーザ情報を取得する方法を探しております。

Web Apps に、Javaを使用したWebアプリを設置しており、
Azure Active Directory を使用して認証を行っております。
ユーザ情報はJavaで取得しようと思っております。

ユーザ情報ですが、Azure AD に登録している web apps にサインインした後、
「[web apps] + /.auth/me」と入力してアクセスすると、
ブラウザにユーザ情報がjsonが表示される為、その情報を取得しようと思っております。

ユーザ情報を取得する為、以下プログラムを作成しましたが取得はできませんでした。
※Azure AD とのやり取りに、アクセストークンが必要とのことでしたので、事前に取得しております。

```
// アクセストークン
String accessToken = [取得済];

// 認証済ユーザ情報を取得する用URL
URL targetUrl = new URL([web app] + "/.auth/me");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();


// 認証ヘッダーを設定
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

// HTTPメソッドの設定
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

// 接続
connection.connect();
```

質問ですが、上記プログラムの一部修正を行えば取得が可能なのでしょうか、
また、他の方法で取得する必要があるのでしょうか。
ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザで取得できて、Javaのプログラムで取得できないとすると、他にも必要なリクエストヘッダーがあるのではないかと思います。

[このページ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152888/azure-ad-get-current-logged-in-user-in-java-jsp-api-from-auth-me?rq=1)を参考に、リクエストヘッダーを追加するコードを実装してみて下さい。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。サイトを参考にユーザ情報を取得することができました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @user31184  解決したら、クローズしておいて下さい :-)